# "lm" extended function. Linear model

Tags: r, function, lm

I have a linear model with almost 0 Rsquare. I am making a function with 1 parameter `n` which describes the power transformation that is to be taken.

If `n = 3` the model becomes:

```
y = x1 + x2 + x1^2 + x2^2 + x1^3 + x2^3
```

How can I enter these in the model without having to write it again and again?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function **poly** in the formula like this

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(y=rnorm(10), x1=rnorm(10), x2=rnorm(10))
n <-3
fm <-lm(y ~ poly(x1, degree=n, raw=TRUE)+poly(x2, degree=n, raw=TRUE), data=dat)
summary(fm)
## Coefficients:
##                                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)                        0.50796    0.81187   0.626    0.576
## poly(x1, degree = n, raw = TRUE)1 -0.54354    0.86195  -0.631    0.573
## poly(x1, degree = n, raw = TRUE)2 -0.66328    0.55169  -1.202    0.315
## poly(x1, degree = n, raw = TRUE)3  0.05989    0.35421   0.169    0.876
## poly(x2, degree = n, raw = TRUE)1  1.06890    1.00518   1.063    0.366
## poly(x2, degree = n, raw = TRUE)2  0.01655    0.76730   0.022    0.984
## poly(x2, degree = n, raw = TRUE)3 -1.18610    0.84214  -1.408    0.254
```

**degree** is of course the maximum degree of x1 and x2, **raw=TRUE** means that it is equivalent to `x1 + I(x1^2) + ...` , if **raw=FALSE** the polynomials will be orthogonals.

Note that the number at the end of the names of the coefficients represent the degree of the associated polynomials.

PS : you can use `poly(x1, x2, degree=n, raw=TRUE)`, to write a similar formula which include interactions.